# How to find the relative energies between multiple frequency bands?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, signal-power

I am filtering my input into four frequency bands using IIR filters.

The output of each band has some disturbances or ripples in it. I am looking for a method to normalize the four bands so that all the noise is suppressed and basically remove the noise power levels from each band. How to identically normalise all the four bands so as to compare the normalised results to find the relative energies between the bands?

Comment: what exactly does it mean for a band to have "ripples in it"? Do you mean noise? or some periodic interferer? Or do you mean ripples in the frequency response of the channel filter? It's sadly not very clear what you mean :(

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions can be thought of:
First and most simple solution would be to take the middle of each band as a reference point.
Second and almost as simple: average over the whole passband to define the power of this band.
Third, you could try some advanced noise supression techniques, but I highly doubt that it is actually noise, that you are dealing with there. Filter overshoot and such seems more likely.